# How can I wrap a command including EOF within a single variable?

Tags: bash, variables, eof

I'm hoping for some help with writing a variable that contains EOF

I want to save the following command into a variable:

```
gmx energy -f /usr/local/MD/Analysis/CY9A_ADP/em.edr -o ./1_CY9A_ADP_potential.xvg <<EOF  
11  
0  
EOF
```

This is what I have tried:

```sh
#!/bin/bash  

a="gmx energy -f /usr/local/MD/Analysis/CY9A_ADP/em.edr -o /1_CY9A_ADP_potential.xvg <<EOF  
11
0
EOF
"

echo `$a`
```

This is the output:
Command line:

```
gmx energy -f /usr/local/MD/Analysis/CY9A_ADP/em.edr -o ./1_CY9A_ADP_potential.xvg <<EOF 11 0 EOF


-------------------------------------------------------
Program:     gmx energy, version 2020.2  
Source file: src/gromacs/commandline/cmdlineparser.cpp (line 275)  
Function:    void gmx::CommandLineParser::parse(int *, char **)  

Error in user input:  
Invalid command-line options  
  In command-line option -o  
    Too many values
```

I believe the variable is being read as a single line.  I'm hoping someone can help me save the EOF containing command above into variable $a that I can run with echo `$a`.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Commands cannot be reliably stored in variables at all - use functions for that. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...there is no possible value you can store in the variable `a` that will invoke the code you want from ```echo `$a` ```, because unquoted parameter expansions only perform a small subset of parsing operations performed when evaluating code. Heredocs (which is the syntax that `<<EOF` is using) are not in that subset; neither is recognition and honoring of syntactic quotes, or pipes, or most other syntax.

Comment: (Well, you could define a function, like `myfunc() { gmx energy -f /usr/local/MD/Analysis/CY9A_ADP/em.edr -o ./1_CY9A_ADP_potential.xvg <<<$'11\n0'; }`, and then assign `a=myfunc`... but if you're going to do that, why not just have your code call `myfunc` instead of calling ```echo $($a)```?)

Comment: (The other thing that _is_ a possibility is to use `eval "$a"` when the variable `a` contains code you want to run, but that has its own serious problems; see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048); the Right Thing is very much to use a function).